# How to delete broken packages in ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management

I can not remove broken package. Use the following command: 
`sudo apt-get -f install`
but I get the following response:

```
Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_0.10.28-1chl1~trusty1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nodejs (0.10.28-1chl1~trusty1) over (0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_0.10.28-1chl1~trusty1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/node.1.gz', which is also in package nodejs-legacy 0.10.25~dfsg2-2ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_0.10.28-1chl1~trusty1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I tried various commands like

```
 2015  sudo apt-get clean
 2020  sudo dpkg --configure -a
 2023  sudo apt-get autoremove
 2034  sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get -f install
```

But I did not get any result. I can not install synaptic. Any ideas how can I remove the broken package ?

Comment: Here few answers has suggested `--force-remove-reinstreq` and `--force-overwrite`. Please note that you should use these two (especially the first one) only if you are a Linux expert , because it can break you system completely.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This fixed my problem:

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_0.10.28-1chl1~trusty1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Really helpful. I almost lost many packages that depend on a broken package. I only overwrited that broken one then everything solved

Answer (score 111):

run this command to remove broken packages in ubuntu.

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq package_name
```

after removing package update your system with command

`sudo apt-get update`

restart system after successfully updation.

Comment: This command should always be avoided as it breaks you system more than it repairs

Comment: @rancho depends on what package it is.

Comment: nice one, the way you gus always write package_name, yet i see a list of 900 lines in a crazy format, for example : `Broken libopencv-highgui2.4v5:amd64 Conflicts on libopencv-highgui2.4 [ amd64 ] < 2.4.8+dfsg1-2ubuntu1 > ( libs )`. waiting on LTS has really done this crazy trick to me.

Comment: @rancho "it breaks you system more than it repairs" can you elaborate? `man dpkg` does not help a lot.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me. I broke my mysql while updating the package. Now I couldn't purge or reinstall. So this saved my life.

Comment: I think **reinstalling the broken package** would have much less change of breaking the system. Try `sudo apt install --reinstall packagename-here`. After the package has been succesfully reinstalled and is not longer a broken one, you can remove it normally.

Answer (score 21):

Open your terminal and use following command

```
sudo dpkg --purge nodejs-legacy
sudo apt-get install -f
```

It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 18):

I've found that:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq <packagename>
```

Works best.   If it gives you an error that it won't remove a package because it is depended on by another package, remove that other package as well.   You'll have to repeat this step several times and then reinstall your deleted packages.

The `force-remove-reinstreq` is THE "nuclear option" of deleting a package.  It only fails if there is another package depending on the one you're about to delete -- Again, in that case, deleted the depending package too.

Comment: THE nuclear option worked where purges, cleans, reinstalls, autoremoves, via both `dpkg` and `apt-get` failed. Thank you.

Comment: This is *the* best solution if you just want to nuke everything and start over. Saved me lots of time! (I also used --purge after --remove)

Comment: plase, can u give some hints on how to fill that `package_name` when we have like 1000+ lines (some duplicate) in the apt log files..

Comment: "remove that other package as well" ! +1

Comment: Use `dpkg -l` to list packages

Comment: It doesn't work. It says `post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1`. How do I remove a package without running its removal scripts? What is the real nuclear option?

Comment: Great info sir, only the nuclear option worked, tried every other option that I could reach to till I found this

Answer (score 11):

If you have a broken dependency (which I have encountered with `openjdk`), you will want to purge the package and force it to skip over dependency problems:

```
sudo dpkg -P --force-depends package_name
```

[I found the answer on another forum](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2423640&s=a3f4d342cd3708ec45f19ea346667721&p=13875606#post13875606)

Comment: This fixed my problem! Thanks for your answer

Comment: I could kiss you! thank you, thank you, thank you.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me after trying a lot of options to completely uninstall a Python version I compiled manually. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 11):

> ***NOTE**: The following command will remove the installation and removal scripts including the list files. It won't remove the package, nor **it will fix anything, it will just make `dpkg` forget about the error message.***

```
rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/<package_name>.*
```

**example:**

`rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/elasticsearch.*`

Comment: This answer helped me find a less drastic solution to the problem. I added `set -x` to the top of the `/var/lib/dpkg/info/$PKG_NAME.postrm` to echo what is was executing. This showed that it was failing while trying to `deluser`. I manually deleted the user, commented the offending line, and was then able to successfully uninstall the package.

Comment: The accepted answer does not fix my problem because it get stuck on pre-removal script anyway

Answer (score 8):

None of the above worked for me.  Eventually I edited `/var/lib/dpkg/status`
and removed the packages from there.

However, I would not advise this.  It's just an option if all else fails.

Comment: This seems to be the only thing that worked for me. Even the so called 'nuclear option' of --force-remove-reinstreq couldn't delete the offending package.
Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one:

update your package list like this

```
 sudo apt-get update
```

then cleanup any partial packages

```
 sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Now clean the apt cache

```
 sudo apt-get clean
```

Now remove any unnecessary dependancies

```
 sudo apt-get autoremove
```

from the command above, you can identify any broken packages and forcefully remove it like this

```
 sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq package_name
```

Finally mopup any other packages with dependacies

```
 sudo apt-get -f install
```

Tell me how it goes.

Comment: I think this command is incorrect: `sudo dpkg --remove -force --force-remove-reinstreq package_name.

Comment: Ji...so which  one is the correct way?

Comment: Thanks a lot. So many suggestions, but only yours `sudo apt-get autoremove -f' helped for Ubuntu16.04 broken squid package.

Comment: @nine9five I'm glad you are sorted. Enjoy your day

Answer (score 3):

Open your terminal , and paste these line after line

```
sudo rm -rf  /var/cache/apt/archives/nodejs_0.10.28-1chl1~trusty1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

then try again

Answer (score 3):

The same error repeats If we do `apt-get clean` and `apt-get -f install` unless we remove the junk data from `/var/lib/dpkg/status` file in Ubuntu.

Suppose we need to remove apache broken package. Initially we have to open the status file and search for the package apache. Remove the entire package description and save the status file. Then try using `apt-get -f install` and `apt-get clean`.

Answer (score 2):

None of the above worked for me

I used `sudo aptitude`.

It found the error immediately and offered options. You select and it fixes it.

Comment: also fixed it for me on debian - this was the only working solution for me. None of the comments before worked for me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with broken kodi package. I opened synaptic package manager and used the "broken" filter to locate the package and marked it for complete removal. It worked like a champ.

Answer (score 0):

1. query all the packages that are installed today or yesterday
   `awk -v foo=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d') -v bar=$(date -d "yesterday" '+%Y-%m-%d') '($1==foo || $1==bar) && $3~/^install$/ { print $4 }' /var/log/dpkg.log`
2. wine-qqintl:i386 caused the problem, so I remove the package
   `sudo dpkg -r wine-qqintl:i386`
3. done.

Comment: ok, we can get recently installed packages like that, but this doesn't answer the question which asks how to remove broken packages