# to remove broken packages 14.04

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

I want to remove/reinstall the broken package libopenni-sensor-primesense0

I have tried all commands i.e

```
sudo aptitude install <packagename>

sudo aptitude -f install <packagename>

sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

etc but still getting the error

```
dpkg: error processing package libopenni-sensor-primesense0 (--remove):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libopenni-sensor-primesense0
```

please help .. I shall be very thankful to you ... I'm facing this issue since long

Answer (score 0):

try this (careful the force command is very powerful and as such it is advised the user fully understand what it does):

```
sudo dpkg -i --force-all [deb file path]
```

`apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` then try everything (including what you tried) again...

Similar problem: [How to delete broken packages in ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525088/how-to-delete-broken-packages-in-ubuntu/) . The solutions might help u if this doesn't work.