# Unable to delete packages

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, dpkg

I am not able to delete the following 2 packages :

```
virtualbox-dkms
virtualbox-ext-pack
```

When I do

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-ext-pack
```

it returns the following:

```
Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and when I do

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-dkms
```

it returns:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
virtualbox-ext-pack : Depends: virtualbox (>= 5.0) or
                            virtualbox-5.0 but it is not going to be installed or
                            virtualbox-5.1 but it is not going to be installed
```

What should I do?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Well, you've stepped into this trap... AFAIK you should clear dpkg package record manually.

Comment: Try this: [delete broken package](http://askubuntu.com/questions/525088/how-to-delete-broken-packages-in-ubuntu)

Comment: @Danatela Tried this ....does not work

Comment: Then you should somehow mark it as not installed and never try install it again.

Comment: @Danatela I was able to remove both of them ....How may I fresh install virtualbox?

Comment: You can, but don't try to install extpack through apt. You can install it usual way.

Comment: @Danatela Is APT not the usual way, or did I miss something?

Comment: @wjandrea, for extpack, usual way is downloading from virtualbox site and installing through VB interface

Comment: @Danatela What's the problem with installing it through APT?

Comment: @wjandrea it fails to install then fails to uninstall. OP had great luck to do standard commands only. I had to clean dpkg db manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Was finally able to remove the packages

First I needed to do

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

as suggested in comments and then

```
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-ext-pack
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get purge virtualbox-dkms
sudo apt-get autoremove
```