# Error upgrading to ubuntu 16.10

Tags: apt, upgrade

I have an error upgrading ubuntu from 16.04 to 16.10, now i have this:

**apt-get -f install**

```
dpkg: error processing package libc6:amd64 (--configure):
 package libc6:amd64 is not ready for configuration
 cannot configure (current status 'half-installed')
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libsigsegv2:amd64:
 libsigsegv2:amd64 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4); however:
  Package libc6:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libsigsegv2:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6:amd64
 libsigsegv2:amd64
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

in the file: **/var/lib/dpkg/status**

```
Package: libc6
Status: install reinstreq half-installed
```

some help?

**UPDATE:**

**dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libc6**

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of libc6:amd64:
... millions of packages...
dpkg: error processing package libc6:amd64 (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6:amd64
```

Comment: As a last resort you can try:`sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libc6`, followed by `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install libc6`. But please read about this option first, it is also said to do more harm than good. See here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/525088/how-to-delete-broken-packages-in-ubuntu

Comment: not working view edit :(

Comment: finally I uninstall ubuntu and come back to debian