# Can not update live server (insserv rejected the script header error)

Tags: upgrade

What can be done to fix it?

```
root@lalala:/usr/share/nginx/html# apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
....
....
....
(Reading database ... 114395 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../util-linux_2.27.1-6ubuntu3.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking util-linux (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.2) over (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up util-linux (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.2) ...
insserv: warning: script 'wide-dhcpv6-client' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'bind9' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service fail2ban and bind9 if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service bind9 at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service fail2ban at depth 1
insserv:  loop involving service syslog-ng at depth 4
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 util-linux
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


root@lalala:/usr/share/nginx/html# sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up util-linux (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.2) ...
insserv: warning: script 'wide-dhcpv6-client' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'bind9' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service nginx and bind9 if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service bind9 at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service nginx at depth 1
insserv:  loop involving service syslog-ng at depth 4
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for systemd:
 systemd depends on util-linux (>= 2.27.1); however:
  Package util-linux is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
Errors were encountered while processing:
 util-linux
 systemd


root@lalala:/usr/share/nginx/html# sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 111 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up util-linux (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.2) ...
insserv: warning: script 'wide-dhcpv6-client' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'bind9' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service fail2ban and bind9 if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service bind9 at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service fail2ban at depth 1
insserv:  loop involving service syslog-ng at depth 4
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 util-linux
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)



root@lalala:/var/cache/apt/archives# sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up util-linux (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.2) ...
insserv: warning: script 'wide-dhcpv6-client' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'bind9' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service fail2ban and bind9 if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service bind9 at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service fail2ban at depth 1
insserv:  loop involving service syslog-ng at depth 4
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for systemd:
 systemd depends on util-linux (>= 2.27.1); however:
  Package util-linux is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
Errors were encountered while processing:
 util-linux
 systemd


root@lalala:/var/cache/apt/archives# sudo apt-get --fix-missing install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 111 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up util-linux (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.2) ...
insserv: warning: script 'wide-dhcpv6-client' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'bind9' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service fail2ban and bind9 if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service bind9 at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service fail2ban at depth 1
insserv:  loop involving service syslog-ng at depth 4
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 util-linux
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


root@lalala:/var/cache/apt/archives# sudo dpkg --configure --pending
Setting up util-linux (2.27.1-6ubuntu3.2) ...
insserv: warning: script 'wide-dhcpv6-client' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: warning: script 'bind9' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service nginx and bind9 if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service bind9 at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service nginx at depth 1
insserv:  loop involving service syslog-ng at depth 4
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package util-linux (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for systemd:
 systemd depends on util-linux (>= 2.27.1); however:
  Package util-linux is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package systemd (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
Errors were encountered while processing:
 util-linux
 systemd


root@lalala:/var/cache/apt/archives# sudo dpkg -C
The following packages are only half configured, probably due to problems
configuring them the first time.  The configuration should be retried using
dpkg --configure <package> or the configure menu option in dselect:
 util-linux           miscellaneous system utilities

The following packages have been triggered, but the trigger processing
has not yet been done.  Trigger processing can be requested using
dselect or dpkg --configure --pending (or dpkg --triggers-only):
 systemd              system and service manager
```

Comment: Fix your scripts /etc/init.d/wide-dhcpv6-client and /etc/init.d/bind9, or delete the packages that provided those scripts.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Impossible to remove. I followed many guides including this - http://askubuntu.com/questions/525088/how-to-delete-broken-packages-in-ubuntu . It became worser --  https://gist.github.com/AbhishekGhosh/2982bc2d577ed147075dd397cff147d3