# Matplotlib is not installing on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. I need to install the matlibplot python module. But whenever I try to install it with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

it shows the following errors:

```
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
 requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
 distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
 or been moved out of Incoming.
 The following information may help to resolve the situation:

 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-matplotlib : Depends: python-dateutil but it is not going to    be installed
                     Depends: python-numpy (>= 1:1.10.0~b1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: python-numpy-abi9
                     Depends: python-cycler but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)
                     Recommends: python-glade2 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: python-imaging but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: python-tk (>= 2.5.2-1.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How can I solve these problems?

Answer (score 0):

Cite:

> Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages

Possible solution:

Run this command to remove broken packages in ubuntu.

> sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq package_name

after removing package update your system with command

> sudo apt-get update

Additional information:

«How to delete broken packages in ubuntu»

http://askubuntu.com/questions/525088/ddg#619956