# 18.04 Will Not Boot After Failed Update

Tags: boot, 18.04

I rarely reboot. Tonight I had some updates that failed (one that I remember was python). I figured it was odd, so I would reboot and try updating again. Only now I get stuck on

```
[ OK ] Started GNOME Display Manager. Dispatcher Service......tem changes.pp link was shut down...."
```

I believe I have kernel 4.15.0.24; I was able to reboot to grub once and try 4.15.0.23, but it ended up in the same spot.

I also tried CTRL+ALT+F2 but keyboard gos unresponsive at that point. My system is a System76 Sable Touch 3. 4th Generation Intel® Core™ i5-4440S ( 2.80GHz - 6MB cache - 4 Cores - HD Graphics 4600 ), so I am not certain it would be the same issue as those with the nvidia cards.

### I am uncertain how to proceed in troubleshooting and hopefully, back up and running.

I was able to eventually get in by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> log in and install `lightdm`. 
Obviously it is just a temp workaround, but there are still more issues.

I get many `python3` & `dkpkg` errors when `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`. 
also:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
 update-notifier-common
 python3-update-manager
 gnome-shell
 update-notifier
 unattended-upgrades
 update-manager
 gnome-menus
 update-manager-core
 gdm3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and / or

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: Get some errors when trying both of those. :-(

Comment: Show us these errors...

Comment: It was too long to post here, so https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/XMpDYYTJkH/

Comment: You could try to force to remove hplip-data by using the hints from https://askubuntu.com/questions/525088/how-to-delete-broken-packages-in-ubuntu and/or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27455626/how-to-remove-an-incomplete-package-by-using-apt-get

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall hplip hplip-data
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3
```

This is what ended up helping me. Thanks to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3-defaults/+bug/1779237