# Broken package of Mariadb

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg, mysql

I am stuck and I don't know what to do anymore. I am trying to install Mariadb and then for some kind of occassion these errors persist like glue.

```
dpkg: regarding .../mariadb-client-core-10.3_1%3a10.3.23+maria~focal_amd64.deb containing mariadb-client-core-10.3:  mariadb-client-10.3 conflicts with mysql-client-core-5.5   mariadb-client-core-10.3 provides mysql-client-core-5.5 and is to be installed.

dpkg: error processing archive
/var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-client-core-10.3_1%3a10.3.23+maria~focal_amd64.deb
(--unpack):  conflicting packages - not installing
mariadb-client-core-10.3

dpkg: regarding
.../mariadb-client-10.3_1%3a10.3.23+maria~focal_amd64.deb containing
mariadb-client-10.3:  mariadb-client-core-10.3 conflicts with
mysql-client-5.5   mariadb-client-10.3 provides mysql-client-5.5 and
is to be installed.

dpkg: error processing archive
/var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-client-10.3_1%3a10.3.23+maria~focal_amd64.deb
(--unpack):  conflicting packages - not installing mariadb-client-10.3

Preparing to unpack .../mysql-common_1%3a10.3.23+maria~focal_all.deb
... Unpacking mysql-common (1:10.3.23+maria~focal) over
(5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2) ... Errors were encountered while processing: 
/var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-client-core-10.3_1%3a10.3.23+maria~focal_amd64.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/mariadb-client-10.3_1%3a10.3.23+maria~focal_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I have tried these

```
sudo apt-get install -f 
sudo apt-get remove --purge mariadb* 
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql* 
sudo dpkg -i --force-overwrite-all /var/cache/apt/archives/ 
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Please help me as I cant install anything

Answer (score 4):

This guidance is helpful:

[How to delete broken packages in ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525088/how-to-delete-broken-packages-in-ubuntu/)

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq mariadb-server mariadb-server-10.3 mariadb-client-10.3
sudo apt-get update
sudo reboot
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt install mariadb-server
```