# Problem while installing cuda toolkit in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, cuda, gpu

After following all the instructions in [CUDA Toolkit 11.1 Downloads](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1804&target_type=deblocal),
the last instruction

```
sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

doesn't work for me.

Terminal shows this message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda : Depends: cuda-11-1 (>= 11.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

PS: I have an NVIDIA GTX 1660TI card in my computer.

Any solution please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Does anything not work after your dpkg -i install, which should have supplied all necessary files?  Might have been a cut and paste error on Nvidia's part from their debnetwork install.

Comment: same issue with Cuda 11.3 on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 29):

I just ran into this issue and solved it by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt clean
sudo apt update
sudo apt purge nvidia-* 
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install -y cuda
```

Major thanks to [this post](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cuda-install-unmet-dependencies-cuda-depends-cuda-10-0-10-0-130-but-it-is-not-going-to-be-installed/66488/6) on the Nvidia forums.

Comment: solved it for same issue for cuda 11.3 on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Matt, the post you referenced had `apt purge cuda` after `apt update`. Any reason you didn't use that step from the post you referenced?

Comment: @user1045680 Good question and good point. I normally try to do the least destructive thing possible when debugging things. If it fails, I then try again with more destruction! So I think I first ran it without `apt purge cuda` to see what would happen... it ended up working, and I posted it! Adding `apt purge cuda` would be a good second attempt if the above list of commands fails.

Comment: thanks matt, this solveddd it for me, Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: The `sudo apt purge nvidia-* ` syntax doesnt work on zsh terminal. I had to use simple bash.

Comment: please revise your answer as i have tried this, on some PCs example(DELL) these command lines will send them through hell of reinstallations and black screens, i have been there myself. so please revise this answer. purging nvidia on DELL alienware will not only purge the graphics but also the wifi adapter. I hope there is a cleaner solution than this.

Comment: FYI, [these instructions](https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/tesla/tesla-installation-notes/index.html) are missing the `contrib` step from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&Distribution=Debian&target_version=10&target_type=deb_network).  Also need `sudo add-apt-repository contrib`.  Nvidia needs more interns to clean up their docs.

Answer (score 13):

I think the issue is the CUDA driver version.  It looks like the installer tries to install the newest version 455.23.05 and the installation actually fails there.

I've solved it by first downloading the local installer and unselecting the CUDA driver installation, so it just installs the toolkit.

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.1.0/local_installers/cuda_11.1.0_455.23.05_linux.run
chmod +x cuda_11.1.0_455.23.05_linux.run 
sudo ./cuda_11.1.0_455.23.05_linux.run
```

In the menu unselect the driver installation:
[image]
If not already done, add the nvidia repo as per instructions  from the [official website](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads) before installing the driver:

```
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu1804.pin
sudo mv cuda-ubuntu1804.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/ /"
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the CUDA driver 450 manually:

```
sudo apt-get install cuda-drivers-450
```

Test by running
`nvcc -V`
In case nvcc is not found, don't forget to add it to your PATH:
`PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda/bin`

Comment: I just added the "PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/cuda/bin" in my path and it works well now ! Thank you !

Comment: Worked like a charm and yes you need setting PATH like Taha mentioned.

Comment: This really helped. The posts above (and below) talk of purging the machine of Cuda related material. Sadly, that didn't resolve the issue, but this approach did.

Answer (score 3):

You have to uninstall any nvidia driver before running `sudo apt install -y cuda`
To do so, got to "Software & Updates" -> "Additional drivers" -> Using X.Org X (nouveou)

Comment: Actually works.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me in resolving this issue is that I installed up to dated version of the nvidia driver with command "sudo apt install nvidia-driver-NNN" and then pointed on it to be used from the Software & Updates - Additional Drivers

Answer (score 0):

For the unmet dependencies, try the following in terminal:

```
apt --fix-broken install
```

Answer (score 0):

The command which helped me was this:

```bash
apt --fix-broken purge
```

My problem was some of the Nvidia where hold back in the older version for some reason while the others were updated and because of the compatibility issues everything must have been in the latest version. This was my error message (notice the package versions):

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-drivers : Depends: cuda-drivers-550 (= 550.54.14-1) but it is not installed
 libnvidia-decode-545 : Depends: libnvidia-compute-545 (= 545.23.08-0ubuntu1) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When using `apt --fix-broken purge`, apt removed all old packages (545) and forced the new packages (550) to be installed and thus everything worked just fine. However, in some cases (like mine), apt couldn't manually remove the purgable packages because it tries to install the new packages on top of the old packages instead of removing all old packages and installing new ones. To fix this, I simply used [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/525163/746382) command with the packages given by the apt (they are marked with a * next to them). For example, I used this:

```bash
dpkg --purge libnvidia-decode-545 libnvidia-encode-545 libnvidia-extra-545 libnvidia-fbc1-545 libnvidia-fbc1-545:i386 nvidia-dkms-545 nvidia-kernel-common-545 nvidia-kernel-source-545 libnvidia-cfg1-545 xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-545
```

After this, I ran `apt --fix-broken purge` again and everything worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

As in the previous post, I run this for Ubuntu 20.04 Nvidia Quadro P520:

```
sudo apt clean 
sudo apt update

sudo apt purge nvidia-*  
sudo apt autoremove
```

Reboot your PC and run this:

```
sudo apt install -y cuda
```

Comment: The OP asked about 18.04, will your solution work for this version ?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate solution of my answer... I know you don't have enough reputation to leave comments, but this probably would have been best as a comment "can confirm this works on Ubuntu 20.04 with Nvidia Quadro P520". Glad it worked for you!

Comment: @MattPopovich your answer didn't work for me! I keep getting the error!