# How do I reinstall opera-stable?

Tags: package-management

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 and I cant install or remove programs, it just gives me the error "E: The package opera-stable needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it."
How do I fix it?

Comment: Can you give a little more context? Did you install Opera via a .deb from their website? Have you tried `sudo apt remove opera-stable` or something like that?

Comment: This might be helpful too https://askubuntu.com/questions/525088/how-to-delete-broken-packages-in-ubuntu

Comment: Yes Fynn, I installed opera from a deb, I have the deb, but i cant reinstall it. And yes I have tried sudo apt remove opera-stable.

Comment: Yes N0bert it fixed my issue.